# Do images in a database need unique file names?

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, parsing

I am working on a mobile app that allows users to upload images and trying to come up with a naming conventions for the file names.  Would an incremental or random generated name work the best?  What issues could you run into if file names are not unique?

Comment: The names really only need to be unique if you plan to write the files to the same folder.

Comment: About stackoverflow - "Not all questions work well in our format. Avoid questions that are primarily opinion-based, or that are likely to generate discussion rather than answers."  Have you read it?

Answer (score 1):

Can you be more specific what images are you storing. For example, if you want to upload the profile pic of all the users who has been added to your database, then you will have to give unique name to the image files. giving same name will create a major problem. Firstly you cannot save two files of the same name in one folder. The best approach would be generating a unique name for the image, save the image with that name and save the same name in the database.

Can you provide more info on what exactly you want to achieve. that would make things easier for other users to help you out.

Comment: Sure thing, let's say every user is uploading images to an "images" folder.  The "images" folder will contain every image uploaded by every user.  I don't know if the file names need to be randomly generated, named by chronological order, or contain user info.  Another example would be Instagram.  How would they name their files?

Comment: you can also name the image something like - profile_userID.png. where userID is the unique id of the user. You can also create a unique name using the combination of datetimestamp and the userID.